# What are the differences between tuples, pairs, and maps?

Tags: data-structures

If i need make value of two data, almost I using map

And I knew a tuple that could be used similarly.

what's different of tuple, pair, map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be language dependent, as all languages use slightly different terminology.

Generally though

- a tuple is a structure that can hold an arbitrary number of values, but only an amount fixed at creation time (unlike a list that can be extended after creation).
- a pair is a tuple that only holds two values.
- a map is a structure that (conceptually) holds multiple pairs and allows efficient lookups by the first element in the pair (the key). They also do not allow the first elements of any pairs to be the same.

Comment: Then tuple is not only using 2 value like struct(can over 2), pair only using 2 value, map is using searching value by key. right?

Comment: Generally. I wouldn't worry *too* much about what exactly a 'tuple" or "pair" are though until you start using a language that uses those terms, and at that point, a tuple and pair are whatever the language defines them as. Maps are an important structure to know about regardless of the language you're using though. My definition here is stripped and conceptual. I would continue looking into them if I were you. You'll use them quite often.